# Facebook Comment Plugin override my header div when scrolling

Tags: html, css, facebook

Yes, like in the title, the **Facebook Comment Plugin** override my header div when scrolling.

This is **before** scrolling:
[image]

This is **after** scrolling:
[image]

**Style** of header bar:

```
#header {
    height:45px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    background: #2D2D2D;
}
#colorbars {
    border-top: 3px solid #DD5044;
    height:42px;
    border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(40, 40, 40, .2);
}
#headercontainer {
    width: 940px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML** of header bar:

```
<div id="header"><header id="colorbars"><div id="headercontainer">
// content
</div></header></div>
```

And code of **Facebook Plugin** is:

```
<fb:comments href="<?php echo $facebook_href; ?>" width="655" num_posts="4"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does setting the `z-index` of the header help?

```css
#header {
    /* ... */
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaquin Trifonoff! A few days ago I tried. But I put the `z-index` tag in the `#headercontainer`, that was my fault.

Comment: @Emil, please don't make trivial edits like that. Semicolons aren't required in CSS if the property is the last one.